# How to include message.properties with thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am using spring boot with thymeleaf. This is my project structure: 
[image]

And this is my App start class:

```
    @EnableAutoConfiguration
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(App.class);
    }
}
```

I have this on my home.leaf.html: `<p th:text = "#{username}"></p>`

But when I run this application this is what I get: ??username_en_US??

I have tried various things on how to resolve this configuration issue. Please, can anyone help?

Comment: Looks like you need to configure your message source (set the directory where spring will look for messages.properties)

Comment: Rename `message.properties` to `messages.properties`.

Comment: Thanks @PedroAffonso & M. Deinum. First I renamed to messages.properties, then moved it under the resources directory, & Eureka! It worked!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Refer the official documentation for spring boot

http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-convert-an-existing-application-to-spring-boot

It says

> Static resources can be moved to `/public` (or `/static` or `/resources` or
>   `/META-INF/resources`) in the classpath root. Same for
>   `messages.properties` (Spring Boot detects this automatically in the
>   root of the classpath).

So you should create ur internationalization file as `messages.properties` and place in the root classpath.

Or you can also edit the default location to a more proper location by adding this entry in the `application.properties` file

```
#messages
spring.messages.basename=locale/messages
```

so you can store your files in the locale folder inside resources folder, with the name `messages.properties` or in any specific language.