# Thymeleaf / Spring. get property key from ModelMap

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have a basic SpringBoot app. using Spring Initializer, embedded Tomcat, Thymeleaf template engine, and package as an executable JAR file.

in my property file:

```
signup.form.error.email.already.exists=Email (already taken)
```

in my controller:

```
protected static final String ERROR_MESSAGE_KEY = "errorMessageKey";

model.addAttribute(ERROR_MESSAGE_KEY, "signup.form.error.email.already.exists");
```

in the template:

```
 <div th:if="${errorMessageKey != null}" class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible" role="alert">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">x</span>
                    </button>
                    <p th:text="#{errorMessageKey}" />                     
                </div>
```

But this is what I see inthe template instead of **Email (already taken)**

```
??errorMessageKey_en_US??
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using

```
<p th:text="#{signup.form.error.email.already.exists}" />
```

When you code this:

```
model.addAttribute(ERROR_MESSAGE_KEY, "signup.form.error.email.already.exists");
```

Spring is not resolving the message from the `message.properties` file: you are simply putting the string `"signup.form.error.email.already.exists"` in the model...

**NOTE** the expression `#{errorMessageKey}` is returning the name of the source file containing the specified message.

Answer (score 0):

Putting properties to Model is not how you resolve the properties in Thymeleaf. See the [docs](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#using-thtext-and-externalizing-text) where they explain how to do it properly.

Answer (score 0):

It is because of Thymeleaf is trying to fetch locale message. And by default it is trying en_US.

You can look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30198162/1125284)